# Dummy coding: code two values $a$ & $b$ instead of $0$ & $1$?

Tags: categorical-data, categorical-encoding

I know there are a lot of questions and answers related to dummy coding. But I still wonder if it matters to code a dichotomous variable d in this regression model

$$y = \beta_1 + \beta_2 \cdot d + \epsilon$$

into any random values $a$ and $b$ ($a$ is not equal to $b$, no other restriction), instead of $0$ and $1$? It is said that it will be the same if $b = a + 1$. Can you explain that?

Comment: What does "a /= b" mean?  And by "categorical" do you mean *binary*?

Comment: ($a$, $b$) is more difficult to interpret than (0, 1) without a rationale.

Comment: I mean a is not equal to b. Yes it's binary. Could you show it only works when b = a+1?

Answer (score 2):

Mostly 0/1 is chosen because of convenience and ease of interpretation, but you *could* choose other values (like 3/5, say), abstractly it codes the same linear model, but why complicate life? You can see some other choices like $-1/1$ which also has easy interpretation.